# What changes do I need to bring to my existing apps on the play store so that they can match Google's new data safety policy?

Tags: java, android, google-play, location

Our app uses the user's location data & device camera. Is there anything to do like- any changes to the code apart from filling up the console form provided by Google?
For reference, I am providing some links below -
[Documentation from google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#:%7E:text=By%20July%2020%2C%202022%2C%20all,through%20security%20practices%20like%20encryption.) &
[Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/10/launching-data-safety-in-play-console.html)

Comment: What is current problem

Comment: There are new safety policies from google. You need to fill up a console form & maybe have to do some other stuff . You should check it.